# How can I add an extra ethernet port to my router

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a router with only one ethernet port and I want to add a wifi booster that needs an ethernet port. can I use a splitter please

Comment: How about a switch?

Comment: How about buying proper hardware in the first place like a router with more eth ports?

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly what you have is *not* a router, it's most likely a *modem*.

It's normal for a modem to have just a single ethernet port. You're expected to either connect the modem to a single PC/device, or to a router which enables you to share the modem's connection with more than once PC/device.

You can get routers that have built in wireless, pretty common stuff these days.

Note that a basic Switch won't work off a modem, you need a router.